# Calculating the average of different investment rounds for different companies in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, average, date-difference

I have a table containing the company_id, investments rounds name(like round A, B, C, or IPO ......), and the date(like 2001-05-07) of each investment round for each company.
I want to calculate the average gaps for different investment rounds for all companies. For example, what is the average time all companies take from A to B？ What is the average time all companies take from B to C？ What is the average time all companies take from C to D？
The table looks like this:

```
|company_id| |invest_rounds_type_name| |invest_date|
---------------------------------------------------
1             A                         2001-01-01
---------------------------------------------------
1             B                         2001-12-05
---------------------------------------------------
1             C                         2003-11-12
---------------------------------------------------
2             A                         1963-03-01
---------------------------------------------------
2             B                         1967-10-10
---------------------------------------------------
2             C                         1970-10-12
---------------------------------------------------
2             D                         1971-01-05
---------------------------------------------------
3             B                         2017-11-20
---------------------------------------------------
3             A                         2017-11-16
---------------------------------------------------
3             C                         2018-03-19
---------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e7131ddc58673c5e88f51bf2d62d5b8)

```
SELECT
    invest_round as invest_round_start,
    invest_round_end,
    AVG(days_required)
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(invest_round) OVER w as invest_round_end,          
        lead(invest_date) OVER w - invest_date as days_required
    FROM mytable
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY invest_round)
) s
WHERE invest_round_end IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY invest_round, invest_round_end
ORDER BY invest_round
```

By using the [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) you can copy the next value of a specific column onto your current. So you can get the following `invest_round` to the current records as well as the following `invest_date`.

With the following date and the current one you are able to calculate the duration between both `invest_round`s.

Now you just have to group by `the invest_round`s and calculate the `AVG` aggregate.

Comment: Amazing. My attempt is so naive!

Comment: @mhawke . . . I would be quite wary of using `order by invest_round` for this.  I think you want `order by invest_date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, I don't. The invest_date is irrelevant for the TO's question. It's only neccessary for calculating the durations. Afterwards I want to order the invest_rounds, since that is what the TO is asking for. It seems correct, to order the invest_round A before B and C.

Comment: @S-Man: I think @GordonLinoff is concerned that the invest round names might not always sort the way you assume. OP indicates that `IPO` is a valid round name. This could affect your query if there happened to be a round named `J` which would sort after `IPO` if such a round exists. What if there is a seed round named `SEED`? Ordering by date would avoid this problem, as it's a fair assumption that rounds occur in chronological order, not name order.

Answer (score 0):

Example between stages A and B:

```
-- table is named 'x'
select avg(diff) from (
    select xb.invest_date - xa.invest_date as diff
    from x xa join x xb on (xa.company_id = xb.company_id)
    where xa.invest_rounds_type_name = 'A' and
          xb.invest_rounds_type_name = 'B'
) as gaps;
```

When run against your data this results in (days):

avg
675.3333333333334

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3559c/23